# Keep getting redirected to verify Captcha after using the verifyPhoneNumber in Firebase causing a null verification Id to be returned each time

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have a function in my flutter app that calls FirebaseAuth.verifyWithPhoneNumber().This redirects the app to a captcha verification process each time causing a null to returned each time instead of the actual verficationId.

```dart
  Future<String> phoneAuthentication({required String number}) async {
    try {
      String? vId;
      String? rToken;
      await _authClient.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: number,
          verificationCompleted: (credential) async {
            await _authClient.signInWithCredential(credential);
          },
          verificationFailed: (e) {
            debugPrint(e.message);
            if (e.code == "invalid-phone-number") {
              throw const ServerException(
                  message: 'The provided phone number is not valid',
                  statusCode: 404);
            } else {
              throw ServerException(message: "${e.message}", statusCode: 500);
            }
          },
          codeSent: (verificationId, rToken) async {
     
            vId = verificationId;
            rToken = rToken;
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (vId) {
 
            vId = vId;
          });
      final result = jsonEncode({"vId": vId, "rToken": rToken ?? ""});
      return result;
    } catch (e) {
      throw ServerException(message: e.toString(), statusCode: 500);
    }
  }
```

````
#0      AuthBloc._phoneAuthHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:aikon/src/auth/presentation/bloc/auth_bloc.dart:56:20)
#1      Right.fold (package:dartz/src/either.dart:200:64)
#2      AuthBloc._phoneAuthHandler (package:aikon/src/auth/presentation/bloc/auth_bloc.dart:54:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      Bloc.on.<anonymous closure>.handleEvent (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:229:13)
<asynchronous suspension>```
````